# If a formula $φ$ contains at most one occurrence of any sentence letter, then $φ$ is not a tautology.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If a formula $φ$ contains at most one occurrence of any sentence letter, then $φ$ is not a tautology.  The only connectives in my system are $→$ and $¬$. I think I should attempt this by induction on the complexity of $φ$ (the number of connectives). Then we have two cases to consider: either $φ = ¬ψ$, or $φ = ψ→ξ$, where $ψ$, $ξ$ satisfy the induction hypothesis. I'm stuck here, as I cannot find a property of sentences that contain at most one occurrence of any sentence letter to exploit.

Comment: A → A contains two occurences of the sentence letter A, so it does not satisfy the hypothesis of my question.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 6):

By induction on the complexity of formulas $\phi$, we prove the stronger statement:

> If $\phi$ contains at most one occurrence of any propositional variable, then $\phi$ is neither a tautology nor a contradiction.

Suppose $\phi$ contains at most one occurrence of any propositional variable.

If $\phi$ is atomic, then it's just a propositional variable, so it's not a tautology and not a contradiction, as there are assignments of values to its variable that give the formula the value False, and others that give it the value True.

If $\phi$ is $\neg \psi$ and the result holds for $\psi$, then clearly it holds for $\phi$ as well.

Now suppose $\phi$ is $\psi\to\theta$. As shown in [this related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507059/if-models-phi-supset-psi-then-there-is-a-propositional-variable-variable), if $\psi \to \theta$ is a tautology, then there is a propositional variable that occurs in both $\psi$ and $\theta$. So $\phi$ isn't a tautology. If $\phi$ were a contradiction, then $\neg\phi \equiv (\psi\land\neg\theta)$ would be a tautology, so $\psi$ would have to be a tautology. But $\psi$ also has at most one occurrence of each variable, so by induction hypothesis $\psi$ is not a tautology after all, thus $\phi$ is not a contradiction.