# Prove/Disprove a claim in logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Prove/Disprove: $A, B$ are two formulas **without common variables** (meaning, $p$ is a variable of $A$ iff $p$ isn't variable of $B$, and vice-versa) and $\vDash A\to B$. Then, at least one of the following is true: $\vDash \lnot A$, $\vDash B$.

Now, as far as I understand $\vDash A\to B$ means that $A\to B$ is a tautology. Hence, it must be one of three:

- $A=t, B=t$
- $A=f, B=f$
- $A=f, B=f$

So clearly $\lnot A$ can't be a tautology and so is $B$.

Am I getting it the wrong way?

Comment: Isn't $\vDash A\to B$ by definition equivalent to $\neg A \lor B$? Because then it follows automatically that $\vDash \neg A$ or $\vDash B$ is true.

Comment: @Protawn - it the condition "$A,B$ are formulas without common variables: $p, \ldots$" is not satsified, the claim is not true. We have $\vDash \lnot p \lor p$ but neither $\vDash \lnot p$ nor $\vDash p$.

Comment: A duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507059/if-models-phi-supset-psi-then-there-is-a-propositional-variable-variable (the contrapositive!), but OK.

Comment: Your argument is not correct for the same reason of the above comment: we have $\vDash p \to p$ and this means that only two possibilities are left (considering your example with $p$ in place of both $A$ and $B$): $p=$ **t** or $p=$ **f**. Then at least one of the following is true: $\vDash ¬p$, $\vDash p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> at least one of the following is true: $\vDash \lnot A, \vDash B$.

Assume not: i.e. $\nvDash \lnot A$ and $\nvDash B$.

This means that there is a *valuation* $v_1$ such that $v_1(A)=$**t** and a *valuation* $v_2$ such that $v_2(B)=$**f**.

But the two formulae have no common propositional variables; thus we can consider the valuation $v=v_1 \cup v_2$ and we have:

> $v(A \to B)=$**f**

contradicting the assumption: $\vDash A \to B$.